# C factorial program using recursion

Tags: c, function, recursion, factorial

The program takes an input, and should calculate the factorial of the number. However, after the number has been inputted there is a delay and the program stops

so far I haven't changed the code much from my initial attempt as I do not fully understand recursion and sunbroutines in C.

```
int calcFactorial(int n);
int input = 0, answer = 0;

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    printf("Enter number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    answer = calcFactorial(input);
    printf("The factorial of %d is %d.\n", input, answer);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int calcFactorial(int n){
    int factorial = 0;
    if (n==0){
        factorial = 1;
    }
    else{
        factorial = n * calcFactorial(n-1);
        printf(factorial);
    }
    return factorial;
}
```

Comment: *Which* number?

Comment: Above !12, the result is higher than the size of an int.

Comment: Also you should post the message that occurs when the program stops.

Comment: This could be causing problems:  `printf(factorial);`  You forgot to supply a format string, so at best you'll get garbage and at worst you could run into memory problems.  Change it to `printf("%d\n", factorial);`

Comment: And make sure you only give the program small numbers.  Factorial grows very fast.

Comment: Why was this tagged with unsigned-integer? There's not a single variable declaration here for an unsigned int.

Answer (score 3):

This statement in the function `calcFactorial`

```
    printf(factorial);
```

has undefined behaviour because the first parameter of the function `printf` is declared as `const char *` while you are supplying an object of the type `int`.

Remove the statement from the function.

Or if you want to get intermediate values then write

```
printf( "%d\n", factorial);
```

Also take into account that for the type `int` that usually has size of 4 bytes the maximum number for which you can get a valid value of the factorial is equal to `12`.

You could use type `unsigned long long int` instead of the type `int`. In this case you can calculate the factorial for a number equal to 20.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int calcFactorial( unsigned long long int n )
{
    return n == 0 ? 1 : n * calcFactorial( n - 1 );
}

int main( void )
{
    unsigned long long int input = 0, answer = 0;

    printf( "Enter number: " );
    scanf( "%llu", &input);

    answer = calcFactorial( input );

    printf( "The factorial of %llu is %llu.\n", input, answer );
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter number: 20
The factorial of 20 is 2432902008176640000.
```

The return statement in the function can be rewritten also the following way

```
unsigned long long int calcFactorial( unsigned long long int n )
{
    return n < 2 ? 1 : n * calcFactorial( n - 1 );
}
```

Comment: `calcFactorial` is a little cryptic for a beginner

Answer (score 0):

> However, after the number has been inputted there is a delay and the
>   program stops

As has already been pointed out by others, `printf(factorial)` has undefined behavior. It should be removed or it should be called properly (e.g. `printf("%d\n", factorial)`).

Not sure why you have `system("pause")` in there as it seems unnecessary.

Removing those two items from your code, I had no trouble running it and getting the correct answer for a factorial up to 12. Again, as has been pointed out by others, your function will only be valid up to `12!` due to [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Other than that, your code could be formatted better for the input, for example:

```
/* formats better than original */
printf("Enter number: ");
scanf("%d", &input);
printf("\n");
```

You can slim down your `calcFactorial` function as there is no need for the `int factorial` variable or the `else` clause. So you could make it look like this:

```
int calcFactorial(int n){

    if (n == 0) return 1; //base case, 0! is 1

    return n * calcFactorial(n - 1); //all other cases

}
```

> I do not fully understand recursion and sunbroutines in C

Essentially, your function will be called over and over with `n`, and each time it is called we refer to that as an instantiation, and in each instantiation `n` is one less than it was in the previous instantiation. This will happen until the [*base case*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#base_case) is reached (`n == 0`) then that instance will return to the instance before it, and this will happen until all instances have returned.

For simplicity sake, let's walk through `calcFactorial(3)`. The base case is reached which is the instance that terminates further recursive calls and returns `1`. In the instance before the base case was reached, `n == 1` so that instance will return `1*1` since the instance before it returned `1`. The instance before that was `n == 2` so that instance returns `2*1`. The instance before that was the first instance `n == 3`, so that instance returns `3*2`. All instances have now returned and the result is 6 and that's what we expect for `3!`.

You can learn more about recursion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))